# How to get non-inherited non-static properties of a class in PHP?

Tags: php

Let's assume I have two classes:

```
class ParentClass
{

    public $foo;

}
```

and

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{

    public $bar;

    public static $foobar;

}
```

How to get the non-inherited, non-static **property names** from ChildClass? So in this case only *bar*?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php ?

Comment: Get all properties via reflection and filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) will help you to get all properties of a class as an array, next you'll have to filter this array:

```
$foo = new ChildClass();

$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props = $reflect->getProperties();

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    if (!$prop->isStatic() && $prop->getDeclaringClass()->getName() === 'ChildClass') {
        echo $prop->getName() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```